# Python development on private network--no pip

Tags: python, pip

The company I work for has taken measures to make our IT assets more secure.  As such, I use a computer on a private network which has ***no*** access to the Internet.  Developing Python software in this environment is very difficult at times.  I cannot pip install anything.  Downloading, copying, and installing packages locally is the only option that I have found and this is hit-and-miss as dependencies are a constant and recursive issue.  I am looking for a better solution.  I hope to find something like this:

1. A tool that will allow for setting up an environment on a machine
   with Internet access and copying that environment to the isolated
   machine.
2. A tool that will allow for a specifying a package and then will pack
   it and all of its dependencies for download.
3. Some other clever solution.

Has anyone solved this?

Comment: When you say "setting up an environment", have you tried a virtualenv? As long as your machines are comparable in setup (e.g. all the same Linux distro) there is usually no problem copying a virtual env folder.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I'm sorry, but I failed to say that my development environment is Windows.  I've tried this approach and have had some success.  It seems that a virtualenv is a way to touch on item 1 but I've had difficulties sharing that environment with other users/machines.  Still work on this aspect.

Answer (score 0):

You can install [devpi](http://doc.devpi.net/latest/) in a server, there you can host some pypi packages or upload your own.

It's compatible with pip, so it won't break your workflow, you just need to point your pip.conf to use your local devpi

Comment: Thank you for your comment.  I'm sorry, but I failed to say that my development environment is Windows and there is no pip.conf. I'll look at using your solution as it applies to Windows.